# Get out / Get out of

Tags: grammar

What is the differences between these sentences (There is No Context I just wondeing) :

> Get out your feelings. (Maybe it means *show your feelings*)
>
> Get out of your feelings.(Maybe it means *get rid of your feelings*)

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your two examples is idiomatic.

The expression: *get out* is widely used (whether of animals or people) as an instruction to mean leave this room/house/place immediately.

To *get out of* is an expression that can be used in all kinds of circumstances to mean to exit, escape from or to avoid, whether a relationship, a difficulty or a vehicle.

Then there is the expression *to out*, meaning to expose/reveal, often used to declare that somebody is homosexual.

Alternatively, there's *to come out*, meaning to declare or admit, also used frequently by gays declaring their sexuality for the first time.

With regard to feelings, one can *reveal/declare/admit/give vent to* (and many more) one's feelings but one doesn't either *get out* or *get out of* them.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out

https://www.plannedparenthood.org/learn/sexual-orientation-gender/sexual-orientation/whats-coming-out

Comment: I agree with what you’ve said, but would like to add one thing – one could say, “You need to get your feelings out”, because _get something out_ can mean to vent or reveal how one feels about something. (Example usage [here](http://www.puckermob.com/moblog/how-to-express-your-feelings-on-paper): _The idea is to get your feelings out on paper along with any desires that you have to insult, attack, or blame._) However, as you correctly point out, “get out something” is not the same as “get something out.”